# How to separate multiple values by delimiter?

Tags: r

My test data:

```
df = structure(list(field_name = c("fruit1", "fruit2"), field_label = c("Yellow fruits", 
"Green fruits"), value = c("1, Pineapple | 2, Mango | 3, Peach", 
"1, Lemon | 2, Apple")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I need to separate the `value` column based on the pipe delimiter and create multiple lines (`pivot_longer`) but considering that the each value has a number that i would like to append to the `field_name`

[image]

My desired output:

```
df_out=structure(list(field_name = c("fruit1_1", "fruit1_2", "fruit1_3", 
"fruit2_1", "fruit2_2"), field_label = c("Yellow fruits", "Yellow fruits", 
"Yellow fruits", "Green fruits", "Green fruits"), value = c("Pineapple", 
"Mango", "Peach", "Lemon", "Apple")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first separate rows using `tidyr::separate_rows` only on the pipe and then use `extract` to create two columns - number and fruit, then `mutate` to add the number to the `field_name`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    separate_rows("value", sep = " \\| ") %>% 
    extract(value, into = c("first", "value"), regex = "(\\d+), (.*)") %>% 
    mutate(field_name = paste(field_name, first, sep = "_")) %>% 
    select(-first)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# field_name field_label   value    
# <chr>      <chr>         <chr>    
#  fruit1_1   Yellow fruits Pineapple
#  fruit1_2   Yellow fruits Mango    
#  fruit1_3   Yellow fruits Peach    
#  fruit2_1   Green fruits  Lemon    
#  fruit2_2   Green fruits  Apple
```

Comment: i like your approach but having issues with values with numbers larger than 9. `10. Pineapple` will yield `fruit1_0`

Comment: edit code and use `(\\d+)` to match successive numbers. Edited code above

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

1. Using `separate_rows` from `tidyr` package we could separate
   `value`
2. Use lead to bring `value` on the same line
3. with `filter` we keep all even row numbers
4. paste for `field_name`
5. tweak with `select`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(value) %>% 
  mutate(value1 = lead(value)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 1) %>% 
  mutate(field_name = paste(field_name, value, sep = "_")) %>% 
  select(-value, value = value1)
```

```
 field_name field_label   value    
  <chr>      <chr>         <chr>    
1 fruit1_1   Yellow fruits Pineapple
2 fruit1_2   Yellow fruits Mango    
3 fruit1_3   Yellow fruits Peach    
4 fruit2_1   Green fruits  Lemon    
5 fruit2_2   Green fruits  Apple
```

Answer (score 2):

Using  `by`.

```
do.call(rbind, c(by(df, df$field_name, \(x) {
  s <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(el(strsplit(x$value, " \\| ")), ", "))
  r <- Reduce(\(x, y) paste0(x, "_", y), data.frame(x$field_name, s[, 1]))
  setNames(cbind.data.frame(r, x$field_label, s[, 2]), names(x))
}), make.row.names=FALSE))
#   field_name   field_label     value
# 1   fruit1_1 Yellow fruits Pineapple
# 2   fruit1_2 Yellow fruits     Mango
# 3   fruit1_3 Yellow fruits     Peach
# 4   fruit2_1  Green fruits     Lemon
# 5   fruit2_2  Green fruits     Apple
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` way. Use `str_extract_all` to get what are not numbers, unlist the result and finally, put the output values in the required formats.

```r
df = structure(list(field_name = c("fruit1", "fruit2"), 
                    field_label = c("Yellow fruits", 
                                    "Green fruits"), 
                    value = c("1, Pineapple | 2, Mango | 3, Peach", 
                              "1, Lemon | 2, Apple")), 
               class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
               row.names = c(NA, -2L))

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(value = stringr::str_extract_all(value, pattern = "\\D+")) %>%
  unnest(cols = value) %>%
  group_by(field_label) %>%
  mutate(field_name = paste(sub("\\d$", "", field_name), row_number(), sep = "_"),
         value = gsub(", | \\| ", "", value))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   field_label [2]
#>   field_name field_label   value    
#>   <chr>      <chr>         <chr>    
#> 1 fruit_1    Yellow fruits Pineapple
#> 2 fruit_2    Yellow fruits Mango    
#> 3 fruit_3    Yellow fruits Peach    
#> 4 fruit_1    Green fruits  Lemon    
#> 5 fruit_2    Green fruits  Apple
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>